# Hook Calling Twice in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am developing a module in prestashop, In that I need to customize the shopping-cart.tpl file so I override the OrderController.php file. but in my module am using displayShoppingCart hook. but its calling twice. I don't know from where its calling twice.. can anyone help me please..

```
public function hookdisplayShoppingCart($params)
    {
    print_r("code");
    }
```

its printing twice in webpage..

Comment: maybe you call it twice, for example in parent class. Please post all your new OrderController.php code

Comment: This hook is called (before the content is displayed - normal display hook behaviour) in CartController.php (line 314) when displayAjax() is called and ParentOrderController.php (line 380) when assigning summary information.